# "Private key is missing or invalid when importing a certificate" in Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I want to test my web app on https localhost. Unfortunately it seems impossible to remove certificate warning from chrome. First, I generated the certificate like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/localhost-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/localhost-selfsigned.crt
```

Then I wanted to add it to Chrome, settings > advanced > manage certificates -> import. I try to import the .crt file generated before and all I get is this:

> Certificate import error: The Private Key for this Client Certificate is missing or invalid.

I googled it, but I found nothing helpful.

I have also tried to enable allow-insecure-localhost flag and open chrome with `--ignore-certificate-errors` but it still shows the warning and broken https

Are there any other ways or am I doing something wrong with the certificate?

Comment: Did you also import the `/etc/ssl/private/localhost-selfsigned.key` file?  That is the private key.

Comment: The browser needs the public key, not the private key.

Comment: Usually you'd create a self-signed *server* certificate and install it in the HTTP server software you're serving your web app from. Client-side (user) certificates installed in web browsers *can* be used to authenticate users when the log onto web apps, but it's pretty rare. Most sites/apps use username/password authentication, not user/client certificates.

Comment: Can you use this certificate to serve content through https and look how it looks like when exported from the browser? should be the same content.

Comment: Also, maybe you are importing from the wrong tab. try to switch to the server tab before clicking the import button

Answer (score 80):

I think what you may be trying to do is add it to the wrong certificate store.  If you're attempting to add it under "Your Certificates", you're gonna have a bad time.  That tab is for adding identity certificates; what your browser offers to the server to establish the browser's identity.

What I think you want to do do, based on your description, is you want your browser to trust the self-signed cert that will be on your server end.  If that's the case, you need to add it in your "Authorities" tab.

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: this works as of Chrome v64. You import the .crt under the "Authorities" tab as @Erik pointed out. Note: FireFox doesn't give you this hassle

Comment: Authorities tab is for CA certificates. Non-CA certificates are supposed to be on Servers tab. Although you [can't](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1776753#p1776753), for instance, manually add non-CA certificate there in Chromium 65.0.3325.162.

Comment: Importing via "Authorities" tab solved my prob.

Comment: FireFox gave me the same hustle and nothing works but okay.

Comment: Importing it in Authorities gave "Private key missing", in Authorities worked but did not solve the problem, in Servers the cert didn't appear.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  It's highly unlikely that anyone would ever have the private key of an Certificate Authority certificate.  I can't imagine why you would be told that if you were entering it in the correct location.

Comment: where is the 'authorities' tab in chrome?  can't see any way to import certificates or .pem. Thanks,

Comment: Find the Authorities tab in the "Manage Certificates" pane.
Settings -> Privacy and security -> Expand the "More" -> Manage certificates

Comment: Still valid answer as of Chromium v85 in October 2020

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Excellent answer. Remember to restart the browser (I had to do so with Brave 1.32). I feel pretty sheepish that I was banging my head against the wall until I found your answer.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was

- setting up a CA
- signing my own certificate using this CA and then
- importing the CA key into Chrome (Authorities).

I got the procedure from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/6735826) answer on SO.

Since my specific issue was for catering for multilevel subdomains, I'll look at it from that angle.

subdomains:

- bar.fooz.mydomain.com
- foo.fooz.mydomain.com

1. Become a Certificate Authority

```bsh
export CA=myca
# you probably want to have this in its own directory
mdkir /etc/ssl/$CA && cd /etc/ssl/$CA

# generate private key
openssl genrsa -des3 -out $CA.key 2048

# generate root certificate
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key $CA.key -sha256 -days 825 -out $CA.pem
```

2. Create CA-signed certificates

```bsh
export NAME=fooz.mydomain.com
# if CA files were in a separate directory
cd .. && mkdir /etc/ssl/$NAME && cd /etc/ssl/$NAME

# generate private key
openssl genrsa -out $NAME.key 2048

# Create a certificate-signing request
# Once prompted, set FQDN to the value of $NAME
openssl req -new -key $NAME.key -out $NAME.csr

# Create a config file for the extensions
>$NAME.ext cat <<-EOF
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = $NAME # Be sure to include the domain name here because Common Name is not so commonly honoured by itself
# Optionally, add additional domains (I've added a subdomain here)
DNS.2 = foo.$NAME
DNS.3 = bar.$NAME
IP.1 = 192.168.0.13 # (Optional, but probably important), add an IP address (if the connection which you have planned requires it)
EOF

# Create the signed certificate
openssl x509 -req -in $NAME.csr -CA $CA.pem -CAkey $CA.key -CAcreateserial -out $NAME.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile $NAME.ext
```

3. Download the `$CA.pem` file and import as an Authority in your browser:

```
    1. Chrome settings (Settings > Privacy and Security > Security > Manage certificates > Authorities > Import). Check Trust this certificate for identifying websites
    2. Firefox: Preferences > Privacy and Security > Certificates > View Certificates > Authorities > import. Check Trust this CA to identify websites
```

4. Restart your browser (Firefox worked without the need for a restart)

Comment: Welcome (out) to SuperUser. There is no need to copy and paste, but perhaps to better explain yes. For the same reason that it doesn't deserve to be closed as a duplicate (it's on another site), it also deserves a full response (with commands). Your answer is basically the copy and paste of the link prologue you posted...just a little more effort to get a more nice/useful answer. HNY.

Comment: noted... updating in a few

Comment: Great answer! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome expects a file in PKCS12 format file which is used to store the certificate, any intermediate certificate and the private key into single encryptable file. these files usually have the `.p12` and `.pfx` extensions.

To generate one use the below command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ./sample.key -in ./sample.crt -out ./sample.p12
```

This command will ask for a password which we need to remember and use it while importing the generated `p12` file into chrome.

Comment: I get error `Unknown algorithm pkcs12` for this command `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 18250 -newkey pkcs12 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt`